# SSHd on macOS Catalina 10.15.3 (19D76)

Tags: homebrew, catalina, ssh

I have SSH enabled (by checking remote login in Sharing settings).

I have also secured it to be pubKey only etc.

Every time macOS updates it overwrites my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` with absolute nonsense, totally insecure.

Worse it *doesn't turn off* the SSHD service.

This is a mess, what I am doing wrong, why would they expose SSH as an option, yet make the config such a mess?

Can I run a different SSH server that isn't destroyed by updates using Home-brew or other such approach?

Comment: Ran into likely this same issue troubleshooting some SFTP connections to my iMac running 10.15.4 (19E287). Have you found a solution or uncovered anymore details?

Comment: @tksb no, unfortunately not. Messy af.